# Hosted solutions for building a simple webapplication?

Tags: web-apps, user-interface, user-management

Can anyone suggest hosted options for building a webapplication that features

- user logins
- a roles-based access model
- the possibility to add my own pages (using custom queries to a database)...?

Something like Salesforce Communities maybe, but with a bit more flexibility and preferrably a solution where the costs don't scale with the amount of users.

Comment: Have you considered using a Content Management System?  It should be able to handle your three requirements.

Comment: @rrirower haven't really thought in that direction, because I suspected the role-based access model would be too far out for a CMS. But now that you mention it... There must be solutions out there that support that. Thanks!

Comment: If you decide to go the CMS route, I can tell you that Drupal does support user roles.

Comment: I've now also found Wix Corvid, which seems pretty great, but haven't tested it myself yet. Might use that for a future project though.